# Error while Storing data in a JSON file in KivyMD Python

Tags: python, json, database, kivy, kivymd

I tried to store username taken from user in a `.json` file. But it dosen't work properly. After the user repeatedly enters the username, it is randomly stored in a json file. Please solve the problem with this code.

- Sometimes the `.json` file is created randomly. But not
  at the first time.

### .kv file

```
screen_helper = """
ScreenManager:
    SetUpWindow:
    Home:

<SetUpWindow>:
    name: 'settingup'
    MDTextField:
        id:username_text_fied
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.45}
        size_hint: (0.7,0.1)
        hint_text : 'Name your Studio'
        helper_text: 'Required'
        helper_text_mode: 'on_focus'
        icon_right: 'account'
        icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_light
        required : True
    MDRaisedButton:
        id:disabled_button
        disabled: True
        text:"Next"
        md_bg_color:app.theme_cls.primary_color
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.9,'center_y':0.08}
        font_style: 'Button'
        ripple_rad_default : 40
        ripple_duration_out : 1
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_dark
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'home'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'   

<Home>:
    name: 'home'
"""
```

### .py file

```
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore

class SetUpWindow(Screen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(SetUpWindow(name='settingup'))

class Mode(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        screen.add_widget(self.screen)
        self.username_text = self.screen.get_screen('settingup').ids.username_text_fied.text

        return screen


        self.store.put('UserInfo', name=self.username_text)
        self.username_changer()

    def username_changer(self):
        self.screen.get_screen('home').ids.bottomappbar.title = f"Studio {self.store.get('UserInfo')['name']}"


    def on_start(self):
        self.store = JsonStore("std_profile.json")
        try:
            if self.store.get('UserInfo')['name'] != "":
                self.username_changer()
                self.screen.get_screen('home').manager.current = 'home'

        except KeyError:
            self.screen.get_screen('settingup').manager.current = 'settingup'
            
Mode().run()
```

Comment: Just a few comments. Not sure if this has any  implications for your problem. The lines in your `build()` method after the `return` will never be executed. And your `build()` method is constructing your `App` as a `Screen` containing a `ScreenManager` that contains two more `Screens`. Is that your intention? Typically the `ScreenManager` is the `root`. And also in your `build()` method, you are assigning `self.username_text` from a `Screen` that the user has not had a chance to interact with.

Comment: You are also building most of your `App` twice. The `sm = ScreenManager()` and `sm.add_widget(SetUpWindow(name='settingup'))` lines are building part of what is also built in the `Builder.load_string(screen_helper)` line.

Comment: @JohnAnderson - Thank you sir for the comment. Actually I am a beginner. What is the way you recommend writing this code successfully and correctly? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your code that does what I think you want:

```
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore

screen_helper = """
ScreenManager:
    SetUpWindow:
    Home:

<SetUpWindow>:
    name: 'settingup'
    MDTextField:
        id:username_text_fied
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.45}
        size_hint: (0.7,0.1)
        hint_text : 'Name your Studio'
        helper_text: 'Required'
        helper_text_mode: 'on_focus'
        icon_right: 'account'
        icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_light
        required : True
        on_text:
            disabled_button.disabled = False  # enable next button
    MDRaisedButton:
        id:disabled_button
        disabled: True
        text:"Next"
        md_bg_color:app.theme_cls.primary_color
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.9,'center_y':0.08}
        font_style: 'Button'
        ripple_rad_default : 40
        ripple_duration_out : 1
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_dark
        on_press:
            app.save_user_name()  # save user name to Json
            root.manager.current = 'home'
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'   

<Home>:
    name: 'home'
    MDBottomAppBar:
        MDToolbar:
            id: bottomappbar
            title: "Title"
            icon: "git"
            type: "bottom"
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: x]]
            mode: "free-end"
"""

class SetUpWindow(Screen):
    pass


class Home(Screen):
    pass


class Mode(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(screen_helper)

    def save_user_name(self):  # added method to actually save user name to JSon
        self.username_text = self.root.get_screen('settingup').ids.username_text_fied.text
        self.store.put('UserInfo', name=self.username_text)
        self.username_changer()

    def username_changer(self):
        self.root.get_screen('home').ids.bottomappbar.title = f"Studio {self.store.get('UserInfo')['name']}"

    def on_start(self):
        self.store = JsonStore("std_profile.json")
        try:
            if self.store.get('UserInfo')['name'] != "":
                self.username_changer()
                self.root.get_screen('home').manager.current = 'home'

        except KeyError as e:
            self.root.get_screen('settingup').manager.current = 'settingup'


Mode().run()
```

Note the change in the `build()` method and the elimination of the other code that was building `ScreenManager` and `SetUpWindow`. References to `self.screen` have been replaced with `self.root`. The `Next` button now saves the user name.